# Guide me on how to use my Mindstorm RCX kit on OS X Mavericks

Tags: programming, software, rcx

Any suggestions on how I can use my old RCX set on Mavericks? I have set up Xcode command line tools, and I am getting compiler errors while trying to download nqc through Macports. Even downloading gcc49 through Homebrew has not helped fix this issue. Is there any other option I'm overlooking?

Comment: I struggled with backwards-compatibility with NQC myself. A couple months ago I made the switch to leJOS, so far its been great.

Comment: Thanks for your response Keshav. I'd ideally like to stick with NQC but even leJOS is giving me issues. Despite setting up the PATH variables correctly, I keep getting "clang: error: no input files" errors when running Ant. Fiddling around with the main build.xml and build.properties files also does not seem to work

Answer (score 2):

I am currently maintaining [my own fork of NQC for use on OpenBSD and OS X](https://github.com/jverne/nqc). As you have discovered, the recent compiler changes on OS X broke NQC in many places. Not to mention that the USB tower integration was pretty outdated. If you can compile it, it should work better than the ports version.

AFAIK, I am now the de facto maintainer for  NQC. (And may Crom have mercy on my soul, etc.)

Also, If you can find the right firmware (available around the usual places) you can update the RCX 1.0 to something like 2.x (or whatever the last release of the RCX firmware from LEGO is).

I make no promises this works at all, but I recall the last checked in version worked reasonably well with a serial tower on OpenBSD and a USB tower on OS X. A serial tower on OS X *might* work with the right incantations and USB/serial dongle.

If someone else other than me actually uses this, I might be prompted to cleanup my sandbox and commit my local repo (and fix bugs others find annoying.)